# check a substring in a string in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need a sentence if...else.. that verify if the filename curbing a string specifies in bash

```
for j in `ls `
do
    if [ "${j:(-3)}" == ".gz" ]; then
        Cmd="zcat"
    elif [ "${j:(-4)}" == ".bz2" ]; then
        Cmd="bzcat"
    else
        Cmd="cat"
    fi

    if [ $j ***contains*** "string1"]; then
        $cmd $j | awk -F"," '{print $4}' 
    elif [ $j  *contains*  "string2" ]; then 
        $cmd $j | awk -F"," '{print $2}'
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use double brackets, which support wildcards:

```
if [[ $j == *string1* ]]; then
```

Also, [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); use a glob instead:

Instead of

```
for j in `ls `
```

use

```
for j in *
```

If you wan't the match to be case-insensitive, you can set the `shopt -s nocasematch` option:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $j == *string1* ]]; then
```

Comment: I worked well thanks, now I can do it but only as non-case sensitive?

Comment: @user2456216 use the `shopt -s nocasematch` to do case-insensitive matches

Answer (score 2):

The =~ operator does what you want.

I personally would use find and xargs though.

```
find . -name "*.gz" -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 gzip -dc {} | cut -f, -d4
find . -name "*.bz2" -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 bzip2 -dc {} | cut -f, -d4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's regex capabilities here. So instead of;

```
if [ $j ***contains*** "string1"]; then
```

Use:

```
if [[ "$j" =~ \bstring1\b ]]; then
```

**PS:** Note use of `\b` **(word boundaries)** to make sure you don't match `string123` in `$j`.

Also instead of using `ls`:

```
for j in `ls `
```

You should better use:

```
for j in *
```